# How to find the expected mean of a very smalll subgroup, while still considering the larger group?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, inference, feature-engineering

#### Context:

For a Machine Learning challenge, I have a national exam dataset, containing over 3 million scores, from over 5k cities (unbalanced distribution).

For example:

| ID | City | Other | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | NY | ... | 85 |
| 02 | NY | ... | 90 |
| 03 | NY | ... | 95 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10001 | LA | ... | 60 |
| 10002 | LA | ... | 40 |
| 10003 | LA | ... | 50 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2999999 | **a small city** | ... | 20 |
| 3000000 | **just another city** | ... | 80 |

---

##### My Goal:

Given another individual, their city (and other data), guess their score.

---

###### My approach:

Generating another column containing the mean of the city, like so:

| ID | City | *City_mean* | Other | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY01 | NY | ***70*** | ... | 90 |
| NY02 | NY | ***70*** | ... | 70 |
| NY03 | NY | ***70*** | ... | 50 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| LA01 | LA | ***55*** | ... | 65 |
| LA02 | LA | ***55*** | ... | 55 |
| LA03 | LA | ***55*** | ... | 45 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2999999 | a small city | ***20 (?)*** | ... | 20 |
| 3000000 | just another city | ***80 (?)*** | ... | 80 |

---

### Problem:

When I have a big city, with thousands of samples, I'm quite glad with the mean.

But when I handle small cities, with very few samples, this average will often be extreme values, too far from the global average. That just happens by accident.

---

#### My proposed solution:

**Adding some virtual average observations to all cities.**

To mitigate this *small-sample-aberration*, I've added 50 average virtual people in each city.

So small sample observations will lean toward the global mean.

For example, with only 5 observations, the mean would be:

`(5*city_mean + 50*global_mean)/55`

It looks like it solves my problem, but **I hate picking arbitrary numbers** (50) and it feels like there's a right way to do this. Maybe involving *standard deviation*, or Bayesian theory...

---

#### Final Question:

**What's the best theoretical approach for estimating subgroups scores, when some subgroups have very few sizes?**

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem for small area estimation. One very simple approach would be to use a synthetic estimate where you combine the estimate for a town with the estimate for a larger area (county, state, nearest 10 schools, etc.) and give different weight to the town v. larger area depending on sample size, etc.

If you have additional auxiliary variables, you could use a regression based model. See chapter four of [this text](https://www.adb.org/sites/default/files/publication/609476/small-area-estimation-guide-nsos.pdf) for a quick overview of some of the possibilities.

Comment: Yes, it seems like so! The question is: How to choose this weighs? I'll check for the book. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: See the equation on the bottom of page 52.